# Bootstrap 5.2 dropdown not working in Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, bootstrap-5

I've installed one of the pre-configured navbars from the Bootstrap website. It is the latest version of Bootstrap 5.2; however, the dropdown isn't working. I didn't touch the code; it's just a default navbar with a default installation of laravel. Why isn't the dropdown toggling?

[Here is a screenshot of the dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZTOx.png)

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
        {{ Auth::user()->name }}
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('dashboard') }}">Dashboard</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
           onclick="event.preventDefault(); 
           document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
            {{ __('Logout') }}
        </a>
        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
            @csrf
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

I've tried researching the internet for a solution.

Comment: The issue you're experiencing might be missing Bootstrap's JavaScript bundle or Popper.js, which is required for dropdowns to work in Bootstrap 5.2.

Comment: How can I add popper.js?

Comment: <!-- Bootstrap JS Bundle -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

Comment: Check this link to see what bundle to add and where to add.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure you have included the Bootstrap JavaScript library: Ensure that you have included the Bootstrap JavaScript library in your project. You should have the following line in your HTML just before the closing  tag:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

This script includes the necessary JavaScript for Bootstrap components to work, including dropdowns

1. Check for JavaScript errors: Open your browser's developer console
   (usually by pressing F12 or right-clicking and selecting "Inspect")
   and look for any JavaScript errors that might be preventing the
   dropdown from working. Fixing these errors can often resolve the
   issue.
2. Check for jQuery conflicts: If you are using jQuery along with
   Bootstrap, ensure that there are no conflicts between the two
   libraries. Bootstrap 5 has moved away from relying on jQuery, so
   make sure you are using the latest Bootstrap 5 JavaScript and not
   mixing it with older versions or jQuery-dependent code.
3. Confirm that Bootstrap CSS is correctly included: Make sure you have
   included the Bootstrap CSS file in the head of your HTML document.
   It should look like this:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   ```
4. Check that the data attributes are correctly set: Ensure that the
   data-bs-toggle attribute is set to "dropdown" on the dropdown toggle
   element ( tag in your case). The **data-bs-toggle="dropdown"**
   attribute should trigger the dropdown menu.
5. Validate Laravel's Blade templating: Since you are using Laravel,
   ensure that Laravel's Blade templating engine is not interfering
   with the HTML structure and attributes of your dropdown elements.

Comment: I forgot to include the script. Thanks for the response!